# removeEventListener no funciona dentro de una clase

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código JavaScript, donde el método `removeEventListener` no me funciona dentro de una clase:

```js
class Removerevento {
  constructor() {
    this._btndos = document.getElementById('btnDos');
    this._btntres = document.getElementById('btnTres');
  }

  btnUno() {
    console.log("Boton uno");
    this._btndos.addEventListener('click', this.btnDos, false);
    this._btntres.addEventListener('click', this.btnTres, false);
  }

  btnDos() {
    console.log('Boton dos');
  }

  btnTres() {
    console.log('Boton tres');
    this._btndos.removeEventListener('click', this.btnDos, false);
  }
}

let rm = new Removerevento;
document.getElementById('btnUno')
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
    rm.btnUno();
  }, false);
```

```html
<button id="btnUno">Uno</button>
<button id="btnDos">Dos</button>
<button id="btnTres">Tres</button>
```

Los pasos para reproducir el problema son: pulsar en el botón Uno y después pulsar en el botón 3. Entonces dice que no se puede utilizar `removeEventListener` en `undefined`.

¿Por qué ocurre eso? ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Hola vtrmq, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Pregunta interesante. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y [mcve] donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar tus preguntas y hacer que tu código sea ejecutable.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el valor de `this` no es el que crees que es. Cuando se llama a una función asociada a un evento, `this` será el elemento que lanzó el evento (aunque la función llamada esté dentro de una clase).

Para que `this` sea el objeto y no el elemento que lanza el evento, debes usar [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/bind). Añadiendo `.bind(this)` estarías forzando el valor de `this` al del momento en el que se asocia el evento y no en el que se dispara.

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando:

```js
class Removerevento {
  constructor() {
    this._btndos = document.getElementById('btnDos');
    this._btntres = document.getElementById('btnTres');
  }

  btnUno() {
    console.log("Boton uno");
    this._btndos.addEventListener('click', this.btnDos, false);
    this._btntres.addEventListener('click', this.btnTres.bind(this), false);
  }

  btnDos() {
    console.log('Boton dos');
  }

  btnTres() {
    console.log('Boton tres');
    this._btndos.removeEventListener('click', this.btnDos, false);
  }
}

let rm = new Removerevento;
document.getElementById('btnUno')
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
    rm.btnUno();
  }, false);
```

```html
<button id="btnUno">Uno</button>
<button id="btnDos">Dos</button>
<button id="btnTres">Tres</button>
```

Comment: Muy bueno tu aporte Alvaro. Digame porque se repite la frase Boton tres el numero de veces que se presiona en el boton uno con solo dar un click en el boton tres??

Comment: Porque `addEventListener` permite asociar más de un evento. Entonces cada vez que se le da al botón 1, se asocia un controlador del evento click al botón 3. Por eso el mensaje "Boton tres" aparecerá tantas veces como se haya pulsado el botón 1.